# Django Validating email address and username in forms.py

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am trying to check whether the entered in email address and username to form has ever been used. The code works fine for when the email address and username do not exist in the database however I get an invalid form in views.py otherwise. I would like a text validation error message to appear in the form when the user attempts to submit.

forms.py

```
 class UpdateProfileForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = UpdatedInformation
    fields = ('email', 'username',)

 def clean_email(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.')
    return email

 def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if email and User.objects.filter(username=username).exclude(email=email).count():
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'This username is already in use. Please supply a different username.')
    return username
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request, slug):
args = {}

#Check that the correct user has requested
if not slug == slugify(request.user.username):
    raise Http404

#Get the user object from the database by its username
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)

#Create a new updated information object to initialise the form with
update_profile_obj = UpdatedInformation()
update_profile_obj.username = user.username
update_profile_obj.email = user.email

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST)
    print(form.errors)
    if form.is_valid():

        #Get the updated_info from the form
        updated_info = form.save(commit=False)

        #Update the user object with it
        user.email = updated_info.email
        user.username = updated_info.username

        #Check if either the username and email address has already been used
        if User.objects.filter(email=updated_info.email).exclude(username=updated_info.username).count():
            raise Http404

        if User.objects.filter(username=updated_info.username).exclude(email=updated_info.email).count():
            raise Http404

        #Save the updated user object within the database
        user.save()
        return redirect('account')

    if not form.is_valid():
        raise Http404
else:
    form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=update_profile_obj)

args['form'] = form
return render(request, 'registration/update_profile.html', args)
```

html template

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% load widget_tweaks %}

    {% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/update_profile_style.css' %}" />

<div class="update-profile-page-container">

    <h2 class="update-profile-title text-center">EDIT DETAILS</h2>


    <div class="update-form-container">

        <form id="update-form" method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="update-profile-subtitle">USERNAME</h4>
                {{ form.username |attr:"class:form-control update-form-field" }}
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="update-profile-subtitle">EMAIL</h4>
                {{ form.email |attr:"class:form-control update-form-field" }}
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class = "container update-button-container" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <a onclick="document.getElementById('update-form').submit();">
                        <input class="update-button center" type="button" value="SAVE">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this code from `views.py`:

```
if not form.is_valid():
    raise Http404
```

What this does is return an HTTP 404 status which is 'Page Not Found', so this is wrong. If the form is not valid, then you just want to render the response with the bound form, so removing those two lines will execute the call to `render` in case the form is not valid.

Also you should remove the checks for already used email/username in your view, because if the form is valid, then those checks are redundant:

```
   #Check if either the username and email address has already been used
    if User.objects.filter(email=updated_info.email).exclude(username=updated_info.username).count():
        raise Http404

    if User.objects.filter(username=updated_info.username).exclude(email=updated_info.email).count():
        raise Http404
```